# New knowledge via HPSG

Tags: grammar, phrase-structure

I've happened to read a little bit of HPSG literature (a certain part from Sag's textbook and a dissertation on prepositions) and it felt like this framework was more of a description model to capture various syntactic phenomena.
**So my question is:** what methods  are offered by this framework to allow one to gain more insight?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is, it offers the insight that human language can be described using a very different theory of linguistic computation than the neo-transformational framework prevailing at the time of its inception (GPSG, the immediate predecessor). They have demonstrated that it is possible to describe utterances if you enrich the representations enough, and reduce derivations to a triviality. At the level you are asking about (broadest theory comparison) it is mostly about the logic of what it means to be a theory. I don't think the theory makes any non-obvious claims about the concept "possible language".